# Joomla 2.5 getInput shows always default value

Tags: forms, joomla

only a little thing I think but I don't see it. In a edit form I want to have a default value for an input form field only if it is a new entry, but it always shows the default value:

```
<ul class="adminformlist">
    <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('invoicenumber');?>
    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('invoicenumber', null, 'DEFAULT');?></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does echo $this->form->getInput('invoicenumber'); not print the actual value?

Comment: Yes, it do so, but if I add the default value, the actual value disappears.